# Username still too long, despite defining custom field

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I was getting errors when usernames were too long:

> ## Warning at /account/register/
>
> #### Data truncated for column 'username' at row 1

I'm using a custom User model already, so I added a new field and made it the `USERNAME_FIELD`:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'
    identifier = models.EmailField(unique=True,default="")
    ...
```

I set this up in a few steps, adding the field without `unique=True`, doing a data migration and then adding the constraint. However, to my dismay when I went to test out my new model, I got the same error. The length of an `EmailField` is 75 (`username` is 30), and trying to add a user with a username of 50 characters causes the error.

In my registration view I sign up the user as follows (this line throws the error):

```
new_user = MyUser.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['username'], 
                                      form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                                      form.cleaned_data['password1'])
```

Should I adopt a different approach? Is it possible to create a user manually without calling `create_user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I aborted this method and just manually wrote a migration to modify the database directly:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.alter_column(u'app_myuser', 'username', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(unique=True,max_length=75))

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.alter_column(u'app_myuser', 'username', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(unique=True,max_length=30))
```

Much simpler.

Comment: Nice one, its a sensible solution to your problem.